# Why are all the obj's loading only on the last element/scene Three.js

Tags: three.js, rendering, .obj

My script is attached below, I am repurposing three.js webgl - multiple elements for loading actual obj's files. Best way I can put this question is "Why are all the obj's loading only on the last element/scene Three.js". The idea is that I render multiple objs onto multiple different elements and this is like an adaptation of https://github.com/rollup/three-jsnext/blob/master/examples/webgl_multiple_elements.html but for obj's:

````
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>three.js webgl - multiple elements</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            color: #000;
            font-family: Monospace;
            font-size: 13px;

            background-color: #fff;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #info {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #content {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
            padding: 3em 0 0 0;
        }

        a {
            color: #0080ff;
        }

        #c {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .list-item {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 1em;
            padding: 1em;
            box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        }

        .list-item .scene {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }

        .list-item .description {
            color: #888;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: large;
            width: 200px;
            margin-top: 0.5em;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="c"></canvas>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="info"><a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> - multiple elements - webgl</div>
    </div>


    <script src="Detector.js"></script>

    <script id="template" type="notjs">
            <div class="scene"></div>
            <div class="description">Scene $</div>
        </script>
    <script type="module" defer>
        import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@v0.132.0';
        import { OBJLoader } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js";

        let checkpointsFiles = [
            "./model1.obj",
            "./model2.obj"
        ]


        if (!Detector.webgl) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

        var canvas;

        var scenes = [], renderer;
        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            canvas = document.getElementById("c");
            var template = document.getElementById("template").text;
            var content = document.getElementById("content");
        
            for (let i = 0;i<checkpointsFiles.length;i++) {
             
                var loader = new OBJLoader();

                var scene = new THREE.Scene();

                // make a list item
                var element = document.createElement("div");
                element.className = "list-item";
                element.innerHTML = template.replace('$', i + 1);

                // Look up the element that represents the area
                // we want to render the scene
                scene.userData.element = element.querySelector(".scene");
                content.appendChild(element);

                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 1, 1, 10);
                camera.position.z = 2;
                scene.userData.camera = camera;


                // add one random mesh to each scene


                loader.load(checkpointsFiles[i], function (obj) {
                    console.log(checkpointsFiles[i])
                    scene.add(obj);
                });
                scene.add(new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xaaaaaa, 0x444444));

                var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
                light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
                scene.add(light);

                scenes.push(scene);

            }


            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas, antialias: true });
            renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

        }

        function updateSize() {

            var width = canvas.clientWidth;
            var height = canvas.clientHeight;

            if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height != height) {

                renderer.setSize(width, height, false);

            }

        }

        function animate() {

            render();
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        }

        function render() {

            updateSize();

            renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
            renderer.setScissorTest(false);
            renderer.clear();

            renderer.setClearColor(0xe0e0e0);
            renderer.setScissorTest(true);

            scenes.forEach(function (scene) {

                // so something moves
                scene.children[0].rotation.y = Date.now() * 0.001;

                // get the element that is a place holder for where we want to
                // draw the scene
                var element = scene.userData.element;

                // get its position relative to the page's viewport
                var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

                // check if it's offscreen. If so skip it
                if (rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top > renderer.domElement.clientHeight ||
                    rect.right < 0 || rect.left > renderer.domElement.clientWidth) {

                    return;  // it's off screen

                }

                // set the viewport
                var width = rect.right - rect.left;
                var height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
                var left = rect.left;
                var bottom = renderer.domElement.clientHeight - rect.bottom;

                renderer.setViewport(left, bottom, width, height);
                renderer.setScissor(left, bottom, width, height);

                var camera = scene.userData.camera;

                //camera.aspect = width / height; // not changing in this example
                //camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                //scene.userData.controls.update();

                renderer.render(scene, camera);

            });

        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>```

[each model in the array should be on its own element but its on the last. I realistically have 20 but in this code snippet above it's just 2 for simplicity. Here is the problem I am getting in a visualization:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9YB5.png)
````